# Programmatically open an external app as popup in Android

Tags: android

One can open an external app like this:

```
myIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
startActivity(myIntent)
```

which opens the external app in full screen without an obvious way for the user to return to the original app.

In iOS when you open the SMS app using `MFMessageComposeViewController` it comes up as a popup. Once the user dismisses the SMS app they are automatically back in the original app.

Is there a way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDK > 30 (Android 11) add this to your manifest:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.package.name" />
</queries>
```

After that you can simply do:

```
Intent intent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT:**

If the user has put the device into a multi-window mode, you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` to try to launch the other activity into a separate window.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the activity should be started as a popup. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` does not guarantee that

Comment: That's a good point!

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get a popup.  I could do the non-popup launch using the code snippet in my original question.

Comment: If the user has put the device into a multi-window mode, you can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT to try to launch the other activity into a separate window.

Comment: @Top4o That flag does the trick, thank you!  Marking it as the answer.

Comment: You are welcome buddy. Will edit the answer for easier find.